# How to disable push notification capability in xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I use a free Apple developer account, so no push notification support. So when I get an existing xcode project and try to run it on my phone, I get "Your development team, "xxx", does not support the Push Notifications capability."

But when I go to "Capabilities" tab, I don't see it there to disable (It said "10 capabilities Unavailable"). So I guess it hides them? But the project still require the capabilities somewhere?

So how do I disable the push notification capability of the project, so I can run it?

Comment: try to change your provisional profile & certificate.

Comment: You can run the app on simulator by making the Team to "None". If you want to run the app on device any how you need developer account.

Answer (score 34):

**UPDATE:**
Thank KerimGökarslan for remind me that somebody can't see push notifications capability.

**If your developer account doesn't have push notifications capability, you must clear current provisioning profile and certificate. Then you can disable it in capabilities tab.**

[image]

Select capabilities tab of your target and turn off what you want. Make sure configuration of every target is changed.

[image]

Comment: This is not a valid answer for OP because when Xcode gives "Your development team, "xxx", does not support the Push Notifications capability.", it doesn't show Push Notifications in the capabilities list.

Comment: @KerimGökarslan If your developer account doesn't have push notifications capability, you must clear current provisioning profile and certificate. Then you can disable it in capabilities tab.

Comment: This is a valid answer @KerimGökarslan, otherwise you will need a paid developer account to activate push notifications. 
It's a pretty counterintuitive workaround but thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 21):

[image]Open YourAppName.entitlements and delete

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
```

Comment: I'm not able to find MyAppName.entitlements file. Please help..I'm not using Push Notification service and got this email from apple : Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Comment: @Nitesh I have update an image,hope this could be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, In my project its not there..So I turn ON Push Notification in capabilities and this makes .entitlements file. automatically inProject and then I turned it OFF again.

Answer (score 14):

Just clear "Automatically manage signing" checkbox and select it again, you will find the "push notification capability" or other capability in **Capabilities** page.

Answer (score 2):

Following this pictrue will fix this issue

[image]